# JScript Code Won't average numbers

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with my code? I have created 6 text boxes. The first five boxes are for any number a user would like and the last box is supposed to display the average of the numbers. I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/DTD/xhtml1.0-transitional.dtd"

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    <head>
        <title>Calc Average</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            var numberOne= 0;
            var numberTwo = 0;
            var numberThree = 0;
            var numberFour = 0;
            var numberFive = 0;
            var calcResult = 0;

            function calcAvg() {
                performCalc(numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour, numberFive);
                return calcResult;
                calcResult = document.numbers.averageResult.value;
            }

            function performCalc() {
                calcResult = parseInt(numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree + numberFour + numberFive) / 5;
                return calcAvg();
            }

        /* ]]> */
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="numbers">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number One</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" 
                            name="numOne" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="var numberOne=calcAvg(document.numbers.numOne.value);" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>            
                    <td>Number Two</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numTwo" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="var numberTwo=calcAvg(document.numbers.numTwo.value);" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Three</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numThree" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="var numberThree=calcAvg(document.numbers.numThree.value);" /></td>
                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Four</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numFour" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="var numberThree=calcAvg(document.numbers.numFour.value);" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Five</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numFive" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="var numberFour=calcAvg(document.numbers.numFive.value);" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average of Five Numbers</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="averageResult" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="calcAvg()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may use http://jsfiddle.net to provide a live example

Comment: return should be the last line in the function calcAvg()

Comment: Your local variables are being defined and then disappearing within each event handler.

Comment: Why do you need  return calcAvg(); shouldnt you be returning only the average?

Answer (score 1):

You are recursively calling calcAvg.

onchange calls "calcAvg" then calcAvg calls performCalc then performCalc calls calcAvg and so on.

Below code should work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/DTD/xhtml1.0-transitional.dtd"

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    <head>
        <title>Calc Average</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="numbers">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number One</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" 
                            name="numOne" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="calcAvg();" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>            
                    <td>Number Two</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numTwo" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="calcAvg();" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Three</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numThree" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="calcAvg();" /></td>
                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Four</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numFour" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="calcAvg();" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Five</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="numFive" value="0" size="5"
                            onchange="calcAvg();" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average of Five Numbers</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="averageResult" value="0" size="5" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

            function calcAvg() {
              var numberOne= document.numbers.numOne.value;
              var numberTwo = document.numbers.numTwo.value;
              var numberThree = document.numbers.numThree.value;
              var numberFour = document.numbers.numFour.value;
              var numberFive = document.numbers.numFive.value;
              var calcResult = 0;
                calcResult = (parseInt(numberOne) + parseInt(numberTwo) + parseInt(numberThree) + parseInt(numberFour) + parseInt(numberFive)) / 5;
                document.numbers.averageResult.value = calcResult;
            }

        /* ]]> */
        </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I have just removed the complexities from your code considering that you just need average of the 5 numbers entered by user. And store it in last text box whenever user changes any of those 5 values.

Comment: There were many issues. Like<br/>
 1. Recursive calling
 2. Needed to parseInt all the numbers individually
 3. No need to change variable for eg: onchange="var numberOne=calcAvg(document.numbers.numOne.value);"
 4. No need to add onchange event for averageResult textbox as : onchange="calcAvg()"

Answer (score 0):

> Update: JS Fiddle link for working, extremely simplified code using a
>   single function and no outside variables:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/cookies/kZZeY/
>
> As you change the numbers in any of the boxes, the average is updated
>   while you type.
>
> Note: I am not answering this for the purpose of doing homework, as I suspect
>   this question might be, but because it is worthwhile to show some form
>   handling methods in this answer because such techniques are of great general
>   usefulness in many applications. Some of these techniques are:
>
> - using `this` in the way it begs to be used in form event handlers
> - iterating through form elements instead of using error-prone multiple variables (*like `var numberTwo = document.numbers.numTwo.value; var numberThree = document.numbers.numThree.value; ...`*) or redundant DOM-manipulation-related `id`s on form elements that already have names...
> - ...and avoiding JavaScript idiosyncrasies while doing the above
> - avoiding non-numeric data
> - using `onkeyup` where it shines
> - avoiding potential math pitfalls like division by zero

My original answer in regards to your code is at the very end of this answer, because I strongly suggest that you completely rewrite your function to be simpler and less redundant and to use some of the features of the DOM, for example:

```
function calcAvg(elem) {
    var n = 0, sum = 0, e = elem.form.elements, k;
    for (k in e) {
        if ((''+e[k].name).substring(0, 3) == 'num') {
             sum += (e[k].value-0) || 0, n++;
        }
    }
    if (n)
        elem.form.averageResult.value = sum/n;
}
```

Each field that you want to trigger the calculation should have the handler `onchange="calcAvg(this)"` or even better, `onkeyup="calcAvg(this)"` for *live, instant* calculations while you type.

As a side note, you don't need any other variables with this code--just the event handler within each field that you want to be affiliated with the averaging process, and the naming format of your number fields beginning with `num` as the first three letters of their name. What this function does is to add up and average all the values in all fields starting with `num` within the form containing the element which triggered the event, with non-numeric values automatically being ignored as well as other safety features like avoiding division by zero and some other strange browser and version-specific behavior that is beyond the scope of this discussion.

---

This <s>may not be</s> is definitely not the only problem with the code (it would help to seem some running or partially running page of your code), but I think I see the main hole in your program's logic.

Within each text input field, you have something like this (local variables to each event handler which disappear completely after the event is over):

```
onchange="var numberTwo=calcAvg(document.numbers.numTwo.value);
```

and yet you have previously defined `numberTwo`, etc. as globals, and your `calcAvg` function only works if they are globals (it accepts no arguments, but merely operates on your globally defined variables).

Remove the "var " prefix within each event handler and see if your program works.

P.S. Also post a JS Fiddle with your page if you know how to do that so that we can "fiddle" with it more easily.*

Answer (score 0):

Unless we use number it will do concatination..

```
            function calcAvg() {
                performCalc(numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour, numberFive);
                return calcResult;
                calcResult = document.numbers.averageResult.value;
            }

            function performCalc(parameters) {
                calcResult = parseInt(Number(numberOne) + Number(numberTwo) + Number(numberThree) + Number(numberFour) + Number(numberFive)) / 5;
                return calcResult();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, real time calculation

Check on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5KgPC/1/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    <head>
        <title>Calc Average</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

            function performCalc() {

                var sum=0;
                var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
                { 
                   if(ele[i].id !='output')
                   sum+= parseInt(ele[i].value);
                }

                document.getElementById('output').value=(sum/(ele.length-1));
            }

        /* ]]> */
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="numbers">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number One</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="numOne" value="0" size="5" onblur="performCalc(this)"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>            
                    <td>Number Two</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="numTwo" value="0" size="5" onblur="performCalc(this)"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Three</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="numThree" value="0" size="5" onblur="performCalc(this)"/></td>

                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Four</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="numFour" value="0" size="5" onblur="performCalc(this)"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number Five</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="numFive" value="0" size="5" onblur="performCalc(this)"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average of Five Numbers</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="output" name="averageResult" value="0" size="5" onfocus="this.blur();"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with Adarsh's changes to the html. This will work in newer browsers.

```
        function calcAvg() {
          var calcResult = 0;
          someArray = [
             document.numbers.numOne.value,
             document.numbers.numTwo.value,
             document.numbers.numThree.value,
             document.numbers.numFour.value,
             document.numbers.numFive.value
          ]
            calcResult = SomeArray.reduce(function(x,y){return x+y;});
            document.numbers.averageResult.value = calcResult;
       }
```